# Parse iOS Push Notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, push-notification

I am having trouble correctly setting up push notifications via Parse.com. I believe my pushes are being sent because they show up in my push logs via Parse. However, no matter where my pushes are sent (app or dashboard), "pushes sent" always displays 0. I know this can be a complicated task so any help would be much appreciate! Below is my code:

**AppDelegate.m**

```
@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

[application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
[self setupAppearance];

// Parse.com setup
[Parse setApplicationId:@"RgOpkkSfRoOFvealb8uUbdElx6e4VwqrNA0ObZLl"
              clientKey:@"GsMpLwqknU9c8qfPY0AaWUZzd7lE38ZTQQliM9TH"];
[PFUser enableRevocableSessionInBackground];

// Parse Push notifications setup
UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes
                                                                         categories:nil];
[application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
[application registerForRemoteNotifications];

return YES;
}

- (void)setupAppearance {
UINavigationBar *navigationBarAppearance = [UINavigationBar appearance];
navigationBarAppearance.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0 green:0/255.0 blue:100/255.0 alpha:1.0f];
navigationBarAppearance.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
navigationBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]};
}

// push notification
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
// Store the deviceToken in the current installation and save it to Parse.

PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
[currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
currentInstallation.channels = @[ @"global" ];
[currentInstallation saveInBackground];

// Associate the device with a user
PFInstallation *installation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
installation[@"user"] = [PFUser currentUser];
[installation saveInBackground];
}

// push notification
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
[PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
}
```

**InboxTableViewController.m**

*viewDidLoad*

```
//push code
NSDictionary *data = @{
                       @"alert" : @"message!",
                       @"badge" : @"Increment"
                       };

PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
[push setChannel:@"global"];
//[push setMessage:@"message!"];
[push setData:data];
[push sendPushInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"The push campaign has been created.");
    } else if (error.code == kPFErrorPushMisconfigured) {
        NSLog(@"Could not send push. Push is misconfigured: %@", error.description);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error sending push: %@", error.description);
    }
}];
```

Comment: You are trying to send the push from your device? And I trust the device has been installed to Parse's server?

Comment: Yes, using my own device. How do I ensure the device is installed to Parse's server?

Comment: So go to your parse account and app directory on the parse website. Check the core data and see if you have something installed in Installations.

Comment: yes i do. when i run the app it creates/or updates a row

Comment: Try pushing some through the website. If that works, something is wrong with your push code. If not, something is wrong with how your app is receiving the pushes.

Comment: it doesn't work via the website. thats why i made this post to figure out what the problem could be. local notifications in the app work tho

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you are adding the "global" channel correctly. Make sure you are subscribed to the "global" channel (since you are pushing to that channel in your code). You can do this in your parse console under data/installations. You can add that channel in your code by using (from the parse documentation):

```
[currentInstallation addUniqueObject:@"global" forKey:@"channels"];
[currentInstallation saveInBackground];
```

If that is not your problem you probably do not have the certificates correctly set up. Follow the documentation very closely to learn how to do this. iOS certificates are hard enough, but when you add another service like Parse it makes them more difficult. Worth it in the end though.